# Problems with google maps api and react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I need to add a map to my app (Nextjs, React, Typescript) that receives latitude and longitude and shows it with a marker.

I did `yarn add -D @types/google.maps`

It should be okay, but when I'm importing it to my Map component from `'google-maps-react'`, it says `"Cannot find module 'google-maps-react'` or its corresponding type declarations."

I look at my node_modules files and there is the google maps carpet and it's types.

Has anybody gone through this? I think it's a problem related to typescript.

This is my package.json:

```
  "name": "wtw-website",
  "author": "Wheel The World Engineering Team <developers@gowheeltheworld.com>",
  "description": "Wheel The World Website, April 2021",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix",
    "export": "next export",
    "pre-deploy": "eslint '*/**/*.{ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix && next build && next export",
    "test": "jest --verbose",
    "test:watch": "jest --verbose --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --collectCoverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^1.0.5",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.3.3",
    "@chakra-ui/system": "^1.3.1",
    "@chakra-ui/theme-tools": "1.0.4",
    "@emotion/react": "11.1.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.1.5",
    "framer-motion": "^3.5.2",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "wtw-icons": "1.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.44.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.15.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.15.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "typescript": "4.0.5"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your `package.json` file and also list your folder structure?

Comment: I added them to the question! :)

Answer (score 1):

From your `package.json` file it seems that you don't have `google-maps-react` installed.

Run `npm i --save google-maps-react` or `yarn add google-maps-react` in your terminal in your project folder to install it.